# How to access and edit data from online(hosted) mysql database

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-3.7

I was making a small chatroom like program in which a user can register, login, send and receive message(in Pycharm). The program contain user details in a mysql database and chats in txt files
i want to host it online so it can be accessed on various computer by various users so what changes i have to make in my code(which is currently designed to work on single computer)

```
import pymysql
import random
def register(firstName,lastName,password,userName,emailId):
    db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","pass","USERS")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    r=1
    while(r!=0):
        id = chr(random.randrange(65, 91)) + str(random.randrange(0, 10)) +str(random.randrange(0, 10))
        r = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE ID = '{}';".format(id))


    sql = "INSERT INTO UserData VALUES('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format(id,firstName,lastName,password,userName,emailId)
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print("Registration successful")
        file = open(id+'N.txt', 'a')
        db.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Registration unsuccessful")
        print(str(e))
        db.rollback()
    db.close();


def displayNew(userId):
    file = open(userId+'N.txt', 'r')
    for message in file:
        print(message)
    open(userId+'N.txt', 'w').close()

def sendMessage(sender):
    receiver = input("RECEIVER's USERNAME : ")
    r = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(receiver))
    if (r == 1):
        userInfo = cursor.fetchone()
        if(sender>userInfo[0]):
            chatfile = open(sender+'&'+userInfo[0]+'.txt', 'a')
        elif(sender<userInfo[0]):
            chatfile = open(userInfo[0]+'&'+sender+'.txt', 'a')
        newfile=open(userInfo[0]+'N.txt', 'a')
        message = input("MESSAGE(Single Line): ")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE ID = '{}';".format(sender))
        senderInfo = cursor.fetchone()
        senderName = senderInfo[4]
        chatfile.write(senderName+": "+message+"\n")
        newfile.write(senderName+": "+message+"\n")
    else:
        print("USER DOES NOT EXIST")
        retry=input("WANT TO RETRY(y/n)")
        if(retry=="y"):
            sendMessage(sender)

def oldMessage(receiver):
    sender = input("SENDER's USERNAME : ")
    r = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(sender))
    if (r == 1):
        userInfo = cursor.fetchone()
        if(receiver>userInfo[0]):
            chatfile = open(receiver+'&'+userInfo[0]+'.txt', 'r')
        elif(receiver<userInfo[0]):
            chatfile = open(userInfo[0]+'&'+receiver+'.txt', 'r')
        for message in chatfile:
            print(message)

    else:
        print("USER DOES NOT EXIST")
        retry=input("WANT TO RETRY(y/n)")
        if(retry=="y"):
            sendMessage(sender)



while(True):
    db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "dineshrashmi", "USERS")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    print("CHOICE 1: Login")
    print("CHOICE 2: Register")
    print("CHOICE 3: Exit")
    ch = int(input("Enter Your Choice : "))

    if(ch==1):
        userName = input("User Name : ")
        r=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(userName))
        if(r==1):
            userInfo = cursor.fetchone()
            password = input("Password : ")
            if(userInfo[3]==password):
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(userName))
                print("WELCOME "+userInfo[1].upper()+" "+userInfo[2].upper())
                displayNew(userInfo[0])
                send=input("Do You Want To Send A Message(y/n) : ")
                if(send=="y"):
                    sendMessage(userInfo[0])
                view = input("Do You Want To View Old Message(y/n) : ")
                if (view == "y"):
                    oldMessage(userInfo[0])
                break
            else:
                print("INVALID PASSWORD")
        else:
            print("USER DOES NOT EXIST")
        print("\n")



    elif(ch==2):
        confirmPass = False
        userNameDuplicate = 1
        emailDuplicate = 1
        firstName = input("First Name : ")
        lastName = input("Last Name : ")

        while(userNameDuplicate!=0):
            userName = input("User Name : ")
            userNameDuplicate = int(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(userName)))
            if (userNameDuplicate != 0):
                print("USER NAME ALREADY TAKEN")
                print("Try Again!")

        while(not confirmPass):
            password = input("Password : ")
            cpassword = input("Confirm Password : ")
            if(password==cpassword):
                confirmPass = True
            else:
                print("Password Mismatch")
                print("Try Again!")

        while (emailDuplicate != 0):
            emailId = input("Email : ")
            emailDuplicate = int(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Email = '{}';".format(emailId)))
            if (emailDuplicate != 0):
                print("EMAIL ALREADY USED")
                print("Try Again!")

        regis = input("Register(y/n): ")
        if(regis=="y"):
            register(firstName,lastName,password,userName,emailId)
            print("\n")

    elif(ch==3):
        break

    else:
        print("INVALID CHOICE")
        print("\n")
    db.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a MySql Database hosted whose IP is `xxx.xxx.xx.xx` and it has a user (e.g `root` with password `PASS`) and a database (e.g `USERS`).

Using [PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html), you can connect to it by replacing 'localhost' with the IP in your code.

Example:

```
...
db = pymysql.connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xx","root","pass","UERS")
cursor = db.cursor()
...
```

Make sure you have set up your DB instance in such a way that it allows from everywhere (`*` or preferably from where you wanna connect to it)

You can verify the connection using [MySQL client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) using the below command:

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xx.xx -u root -pPASS

# To see the list of databases after getting connected
>show databases;
```

Comment: Can I have just a database hosted without an website build

Comment: And how I put my chat txt files online as well Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you can have a database without a website. These are completely two different things. You would have to either purchase an online VM or go for a free options like Google Cloud platform free Tier, here is a [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-databases) which explains how to set up a CloudSql database, it's fairly simple. You can checkout other resources for more details. Also, accept the answer if it solves the problem asked in the question and ask a new question regarding your other queries. Comments are not a great place for questions and answers 

Answer (score 0):

Where to begin? There are probably several approaches you could take but by far the most common is to have a presentation front-end that is based on `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` with a server-side back-end written in Python.

1. So, if you do not already know HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you need to learn these technologies.
2. You need to get an account with an Internet Service Provider (ISP) so that you will have a website that will host your application.
3. Ideally, the ISP will support `Web Server Gateway Interface` (WSGI) Python applications. If not, you will have to program to the `Common Gateway Interface` (CGI) specification.
4. You will need at minimum a login page that will output an HTML `form` that will accept a user id and password and login a user and maintain login information in a `session`. On successful login the user will be *redirected* to your page that will have forms for sending a message or viewing an old message.
5. You want your messages to be stored in a database. Otherwise you will need to implement a `locking` mechanism to serialize access to the files.

I haven't explained what `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript`, `WSGI`, `CGI`, etc. are -- it would take too long. This is for you to investigate.